# h:commandButton click trigger when click other button

Tags: jsf

I want to trigger button2 when clicked commandLink which id "button1"

Button1 Code:

```
<h:commandLink title="Edit" id="button1">
<f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{bean.model}" value="#{model}" />                 
</h:commandLink>
```

Button2 Code:

```
<h:commandButton id="button2" value="Remove Selection" action="#{bean.removeSelection}" rendered="#{not empty bean.selectionItems}">
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Why are you attempting to use undocumented attributes on the `<h:commandButton>`? I have never seen `oncomplete` and `rerender` being doucmented [here](https://javaserverfaces.github.io/docs/2.3/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html). Didn't you intend to use `<a4j:commandButton>` instead? You tagged the question with [richfaces] but I'm not seeing anything RichFaces in the code.

Comment: @BalusC thanks I edited. remove fault using tag parameter and tag

Comment: Split your problem in two... 1: How can I fake a click on a commandButton (from javascript?), 2: how can I call javascript from a commandButton. But keep in mind, faking clicks on another component is sort of useless when not doing ajax...

Comment: @Kukeltje  I agree to you,  this is faking click problem and it is seeing useless as your say when I read your reply

Comment: Of you don't use ajax... you **can start using it**

Comment: While definetly possible (for example by using the `onclick` attribute and sending a `click()` event to button2) - simulating clicks from one component to another somehow points to a design problem.  Why exactly do you need to do this ? Generally it make more sense to merge the "business logic" for the two events into one.